Problem decoding Google News URLS that contain consent information
I have a particular problem decoding base64 Google News URLs in Python when they do not only contain a URL but also consent information.
Based on the older issue decoding Google news urls, I wrote the following function within a larger script that correctly decodes 99% of my URLs:
def decode_google_url(e):
    global faulty_urls
    faulty_urls=[]
    # trim leading/trailing whitespace
    e = e.strip()
    # decode string to get target URL
    try:
        target_url = base64.b64decode(e)[4:].decode('utf-8', "backslashreplace").split('\\')[0]
        target_urls.append(target_url)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error decoding URL: {ex}")
        # all exceptions are triggered by links that contain consent information as well as URLs
        faulty_urls.append(e)

    return faulty_urls
    return target_urls

As you can see in the comment, exceptions are triggered by encoded URLs that also seem to contain consent information. One example is the following string of 276 characters, which base64 in my script does not decode because it allegedly does not represent a multiple of 4:
CBMiYWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnRpbWVzb2Zpc3JhZWwuY29tL2Zvci15ZWFycy1uZXRhbnlhaHUtcHJvcHBlZC11cC1oYW1hcy1ub3ctaXRzLWJsb3duLXVwLWluLW91ci1mYWNlcy_SAWVodHRwczovL3d3dy50aW1lc29maXNyYWVsLmNvbS9mb3IteWVhcnMtbmV0YW55YWh1LXByb3BwZWQtdXAtaGFtYXMtbm93LWl0cy1ibG93bi11cC1pbi1vdXItZmFjZXMvYW1wLw==
When I put this into an online decoder, I get the following information:
"I am at least 18 years old and I consent to the processing of my personal data in accordance with this website's privacy policy.
https://www.timesofisrael.com/for-years-netanyahu-propped-up-hamas-now-its-blown-up-in-our-faces- https://www.timesofisrael.com/for-years-netanyahu-propped-up-hamas-now-its-blown-up-in-our-faces/map/"
Stripping the consent information and icon from the string to keep only the URL would not be a problem, but I cannot even get to this decoded result in my script because the input string triggers an error.

Unfortunately, I could not yet fix the issue with the string decoding, but I was able to scrape the news I needed using the newspaper3k package. I still got some 401 errors for some pay-walled websites etc., but I could exclude those via a simple error handling and focus on the publicly available sites. Google consent forms were no longer an issue.

In 2024, I attempted to use base64 decoding, but it didn't work. Afterward, I discovered a solution in TypeScript and converted it to Python.
Github Link
